# Adding new Sheets at the beginning rather than the end of existing sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking to insert new sheets to my existing spreadsheet.

When I add a new sheet, it gets added to the right of the last tab.

The spreadsheet includes a sheet that gets added each day   and named for the month and day of the year like `2.19`, `2.20`, `2.21`, etc.

I want to reverse the order so the sheets are in descending order by date so I don't have to scroll through all the older sheets to get to the most recent ones.

How can I get Sheets to insert new Sheets at the beginning instead of the end of the other sheets?

Answer (score 1):

Sheets doesn't insert new tabs at the end of the other tabs but rather to the right of the current tab.

If you reorder your Sheets in descending order, then select the first tab when you add a new sheet it will be added as the second tab and it is a simple matter to move it to the first position.

An alternative is to create a macro for adding new Sheets or a Google Apps Script to reorder them, but as a beginner Sheets user you may wish to keep things simple.